# Using Drupal for non-Drupal Authentication

Tags: apache, drupal

I have an Apache webserver with Drupal on the web root.  I also have some non-Drupal content in subdirectories of the root. I would like it so that the non-Drupal content is not accessible unless the user has logged into Drupal first.

I've come across using mod_auth_mysql ([enter link description here](http://drupal.org/node/156547)), but that is not quite what I want. It requires that the user log in twice (once to Drupal, and once for the non-Drupal content).

I imagine the solution would be something like having .htaccess run a script to determine if the user is logged in.  This script would have to be connected to the Drupal system.

Is it possible to use .htaccess to run a script to determine if access should be granted?

Or is there a better solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented this by partially loading Drupal (through DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_SESSION) then checking the $user global.

```
<?php
$base_url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$drupal_path = "../../";
$cdir = getcwd();
chdir($drupal_path);
require_once 'includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_SESSION);
chdir($cdir);

global $user;

$access_granted = in_array('authenticated user', $user->roles);
    if (!$access_granted):
            //Show page
        else:
            //Show access denied
        endif;
 ?>
```

Comment: That's part of the solution I was looking for, but instead of "//Show Page" I'd like print "1"; and "//Show access denied", print "0".  Then have a module (kind of like mod_auth_external) parse that result and display pages in a subdirectory under the webroot...  I guess the problem is that I would only like a single sign on, instead of Apache asking for username/password for the non-Drupal content

Comment: I see, I assumed you just wanted a way to protect some static HTML pages or something similar, in which case you could just throw this on those pages. I am not aware of a solution that does quite what you want.